# ¿Cómo acceder a los parámetros de la línea de comandos?

Tags: rust

He estado buscando en el [tutorial de Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/README.html) y no he encontrado como recoger los parámetros de la línea de comandos.

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de acceder a los parámetros pasados por la línea de comandos desde el main?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes acceder a los argumentos de la línea de comandos usando las funciones de [`std::env::args`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args.html) o [`std::env::args_os`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/env/fn.args_os.html).

Ambas funciones devuelven un iterador sobre los argumentos. El primero itera sobre `Strings` (que son sencillos de tratar) pero lanza un *panic* si uno de los argumentos no tiene formato unicode valido. El segundo itera sobre `OsStrings` y nunca lanza un *panic*.

Ten en cuenta que el primer argumento del iterador es el nombre del propio programa (por convención en la mayoría de sistemas operativos), por lo tanto el primer argumento es el segundo elemento del iterador.

Una forma sencilla de trabajar con los regultados de `args` es convertirlo a `Vec`.

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
     let args: Vec<_> = env::args().collect();
     if args.len() > 1 {
            println!("El primer argumento es {}", args[1]);
     }
}
```

Puedes usar todas las [herramientas](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html) estándar que ofrece el iterador para trabajar con este argumento. Por ejemplo, para devolver solo el primer argumento:

```
use std::env;

fn main() {
     if let Some(arg1) = env::args().nth(1) {
          println!("El primer argumento es {}", arg1);
     }
}
```

También puedes encontrar librerías en [crates.io](https://crates.io/) para parsear argumentos de la línea de comandos:

- [docopt](https://crates.io/crates/docopt): solo tienes que escribir el mensaje de ayuda, y el código
  para parsear se genera.
- [clap](https://crates.io/crates/clap): describes las opciones que quieres para parsear usando la API
  fluent. Es más rápido que docopt y te ofrece más control.
- [getopts](https://crates.io/crates/getopts): es un port de la popular librería de C. De menor nivel y
  ofrece aun más control.

*PD: Respuesta original del usuario [barjak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619320/how-to-access-command-line-parameters)*